# Scheffe Test in R

Tags: r, testing, posthoc

I have 3 groups: `Control`, `Experimental 1`, `Experimental 2`. I am trying to run a `Scheffe Test` comparing the means of `Experimental Groups 1 & 2` compared to the mean of the `Control group`.

I have tried a regular `ScheffeTest(x=model)`, but that gives me the comparisons of each group (i.e. `Control/Exp1; Control/Exp2; Exp1;Exp2`).

How would I be able to compare the means of both experimental groups together with that of the control group?

> ScheffeTest(x=model)

```
  Posthoc multiple comparisons of means : Scheffe Test 
    95% family-wise confidence level

$Morality
                      diff     lwr.ci     upr.ci    pval    
Exp 1-Control     -18.955128 -29.029235 -8.8810211 3.3e-05 ***
Exp 2-Control     -9.908715 -20.352044  0.5346142  0.0672 .  
Exp 1-Exp 2        9.046414  -1.741866 19.8346927  0.1208    

---
Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

As you can see, it is comparing each group, but I would like to only compare both experimental groups together versus the control

Comment: Set the contrasts with the `contrast` parameter. I think `matrix(c(-1, 0.5, 0.5), ncol=1)` might work, but you might want to ask this question on CrossValidated.

Comment: @January
That worked perfectly, thank you so much!! It won't let me mark your comment as a correct answer, feel free to re-submit it as an answer so I can mark it as solved :)

Comment: No worries, it's OK!

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the comparison by using an appropriate contrast, specified with the `contrast` parameter. For example, `contrasts=matrix(c(-1, 0.5, 0.5), ncol=1)` should result in a comparison of Controls in your example against the two remaining groups.